# Why aren't links inside an iframe in a phonegap application working?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, iframe

I'm developing a Phonegap application. One of my pages contains an iframe from Facebook to show posts from a facebook-page. So far so good. On Android, the links within the iframe don't work. Nothing happens when I click them. I haven't confirmed if the same issue occurs on iOS. Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it?

To clarify what behaviour I want: All links inside the iframe from facebook should open up in an external browser outside my app. Right now, nothing happens at all.

What I've tested: I created a simple html file with a link. I iframed that html file. The link doesn't work. When putting in the link directly (not through an iframe) the link works.

Obvious, but please note: I can't change the html in the iframe coming from facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem starting from cordova version cli-6.0.0 and I solved replacing every link into the iframe programmatically with "onclick" event setting the document.location.href

This is the code I put into the cordova widget:

```
fix_link = function()
{ 
    $("a").each(function () { 
        $(this).attr("dest_url", $(this).attr("href")) 
        $(this).removeAttr("href") 
        $(this).click(function () { 
            document.location.href = $(this).attr("dest_url");
        })
    });
}

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function () {
    document.framewrap.eval("fix_link_func = " + String(fix_link));
    document.framewrap.eval("fix_link_func();");
}; 
iframe.src = 'http://www.yoursite.com';
iframe.id = "framewrap";
iframe.name = "framewrap";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

let me know if you find a better solution!

Comment: I don't have time to try this right now but if it works, it would definitely be better than to write native code for iOS and android to intercept clicks. One could even create a simple link with a data tag like "data-iframe-fix-links" and then a script could remake all those links with the data tag to iframes with the fix link. I'll try this in my next project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what is your actual req. But I'm using iframe to load an external page in cordova 3.5 project and it loads the page all right.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com/" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

I came across some padding issues which jquery mobile puts around its pages I guess so for the div in which I load the iframe I remove the padding as:

```
/*for devcontent to remove the default jquery mobile padding*/
#devContent{
     padding: 0em !important;
 }
```

I also had a requirement to open links in the mobile system browser when tapped on for which I used an SO answer to tweak the native iOS code as:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *str = url.absoluteString;
    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"http://"];
    NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:@"https://"];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound || range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}
```

I'm yet to find a solution to open links in the system browser on android when the user clicks. The links keep opening up inside the app itself.

Let me know how this worked out. 
Cheers.

Comment: I managed to intercept the click on iOS according to your code snippet. So that part is done. Now I still have to figure this out on Android. It seems it's tougher on Android, since links within iframes don't seem to work at all. I'll update if I find out more.

Comment: glad it helped. I'm still not able to open links in the sys browser on android on user tap. If you are trying out email link, then just use mailto as used in normal html, that works well for opening the native email apps. Also iframe loads other websites all right with my code but not facebook when I tried to do that.

Comment: @Emiam i've used the same method for opening links in iframe on android and it's worked. What is the exact issue you are facing? I missed this from your comment the last time.

Comment: @Gallwynmasc  iframe cannot have width and height in percentage.